# Where do I install the Slim framework on my ubuntu ec2 server?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache2, slim

I am using Amazon Web Services to create a ubuntu EC2 server. I installed apache2, php, mysql on it already. Now I need to install Slim, but I'm not sure where. Do I do this in /var/www ?

I have never done this before and I am still not sure what the purpose of Slim is to be honest. I have just been instructed to install Slim on my server, and I just want to know where.

Thank you

edit: See below. I stored it in /var/www/html on my amazon EC2 server

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. For those with the same problem, view the following URL's: [link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNr7YqjjzOY&index=2&list=PLapkFDsRUJK62sKMwEyu7-jx2Weo_HDg-)  , [link 2](http://jeremykendall.net/2014/07/28/from-zero-to-slim-framework-getting-your-first-project-off-the-ground/) ,  [link3](https://gist.github.com/jeremeamia/4512646) (use sudo in front of most of the commands on the third link)

Answer (score 0):

To install Slim in your ES2 Ubuntu instance:

1. Connect to your Ubuntu instance using SSH.
2. Navigate to var/www
3. Install Composer ([follow this link](https://getcomposer.org/download/)).
4. Install Slim from Composer:

   ```
   composer require slim/slim "^3.0"
   ```
5. Create a new project with Slim or just use the default one.
6. Create a local file index.php with the default code and then 
   upload it to the Slim directory in var/www/MyProject
7. Create an .htaccess file in the same directory as index.php containing:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
   ```
8. Navigate to your conf file of Apache by typing this command:

   ```
   sudoe nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
9. Find the var/www directory and change

   ```
   AllowOverride none
   ```

   to

   ```
   AllowOverride All
   ```

   and then save the file.
10. Restart your Apache service by typing

    ```
    sudo service apache2 restart
    ```

That's all.

I suppose you can access your instance via SSH and get a full control of your Ubuntu instance terminal.