# HTTP Error 500 with Slim Framework on Linux (EC2 AWS)

Tags: php, rest, slim

I'm using the Slim framework to create a Rest API on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance. But I have problems to make "Hello World" with the example provided on the framework website. Whenever I access the route appears HTTP error 500.

I installed the composer as requested and it is worth mentioning that the Apache and PHPinfo page are working.

I do not know if it has any relevance, but the PHP I am using is 7.

```
<?php
        use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
        use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $app = new \Slim\App;
        $app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
            $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
            $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

            return $response;
        });
        $app->run();
?>
```

Comment: Any more information from error logs on your server?

Comment: Check my answer Here [Configer Slim on AWS ES2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204853/where-do-i-install-the-slim-framework-on-my-ubuntu-ec2-server/39628524#39628524)